# Etsy API: Can I get a number of active listings by shop id without paginating through all listing items

Tags: etsy

I want to know the total number of active listings by shop id. Is there any such API available ?

I could find the API which returns paginated results for all the listings in a shop.

```
'/shops/:shop_id/listings/active'
```

I cannot give a limit of over 100 in this API and for fetching total count of all listings, I will have to make a lot of requests is the listings are lets say several thousands. A simple API endpoint that can get the count of total active listings would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

It's included in the standard response:

`{
     "count":integer,
     "results": [
         { result object }
     ],
     "params": { parameters },
     "type":result type
}`

Docs can be found here: https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/api_basics#section_standard_response_format

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

The response contains a `count` field which gives the exact count of the active listings.

Comment: Where in the documentation is this and can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

100 is the highest limit you can set—you will need to use the "page" parameter to move to the next 100 and so on.